# Minishift Error While Downloading OC Binary Version

Tags: openshift, minishift

I am trying to install minishift on Windows. However, I am facing with below Issue while installing It.I have tried with multiple version of Open Shift

Command Used : **minishift.exe start --vm-driver virtualbox**

Console Out Put :

**-- Downloading OpenShift v3.9.0 checksums ... OKError starting the cluster: Error attempting to download and cache 'oc': Failed to validate hash - expected: 7ed04f7bc411056425d98aa6a10536fab15bdb569549446223f6ed22421ea4e6, actual: 705eb110587fdbd244fbb0f93146a643b24295cfe2410ff9fe67a0e880912663**

Is their anyway to skip hash validation Check..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no option to disable hash validation check. However there is a workaround for your issue, you can download the binary manually and put it into Minishift home - then Minishift on next start will not attempt to download it.

1. Download oc v3.9.0 release for Windows from [its release page](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v3.9.0)
2. Extract
3. Move oc.exe binary to .minishift/cache/oc/v3.9.0/windows/oc.exe
4. Start Minishift

Similar steps will also apply for other platforms and versions of oc. You can search for all releases by tag at [Origin release page](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tags).

**Reason of failure:**

I have checked both Checksum on release and actual sha256sum of the binary and your sum is correct. Is it possible that the CHEKSUM file is cached on your proxy? What is the version of Minishift you are using?

If you are willing to invest some of your time, you can [create an issue on Minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/issues/new) so the team can take a deeper look into the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on macOS with oc v3.10.0.  I tried copying the binary to ~/.minishift/cache/oc/v3.10.0/mac/oc , but when I try minishift start, it tries to download it again and fails on the hash check.

Answer (score 0):

you might receive a 403 forbidden status from GitHub if your request exceeds the rate limit for your IP address.Instead of waiting for GitHub to reset the limit for your IP address, you can create a Personal API Tokens from your personal GitHub account.
Personal API Token generation URL: https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens

You need to set Token to environment variable.
For windows10: set MINISHIFT_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=<token_ID>
For Linux: export MINISHIFT_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=<token_ID>

Then run below command on windows CMD:
minishift.exe start --vm-driver virtualbox